# Why won't my JSP remove cookie

Tags: java, jsp, cookies, content-type

I want to delete a cookie in my login page, no matter what I do, it just won't go away.  in chrome developer, it shows the response from the server contains no cookie even though I had add it using `response.addCookie()`.

Here's the JSP code that removes the code.  It's at the beginning of the page, right after the content-type being set and before any output.  this JSP is in the tile view (not sure if it makes any difference). I also tried moving this code to the containing JSP, but no help either.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%
// remove cookie.  all the properties (domain, path secure) match those those when   the cookie was being created and set.
Cookie ck = new Cookie(someName,"");
ck.setMaxAge(0);
ck.setValue("");
ck.setPath("/");
ck.setDomain(someDomain);
    ck.setSecure(true);
response.addCookie(ck);
System.out.println("wwwwwww 999991111");
%>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
cookie.setPath(request.getContextPath());
```

your code only works if the application is deployed to the root.

Comment: My app is indeed deployed to the root.  the above cookie removal code is also used in my spring logout handler (a spring controller).  when the user clicks on logout, the cookie does get removed, it only fails when the code is run in a jsp (when user clicks on login jsp).

Comment: So, the solution will be to write the login controller and remove cookie there.